# Julia: Testing function in interactive session

Tags: function, arguments, julia

I am not sure if it is possible, but I would like to be able to grab the default argument values of a function and test them and the code within my functions without having to remove the commas (this is especially useful in the case when there are many arguments).

In effect, I want to be able to have commas when sending arguments into the function but not have those commas if I copy and paste the arguments and run them by themselves.

For example:

```
function foo(
    x=1,
    y=2,
    z=3
  ) 

  bar(x,y,z)
end
```

Now to test pieces of the function outside of the code block, copy and paste

```
x=1,
y=2,
z=3

bar(x,y,z)
```

But this gives an error because there is a comma after `x=1`

Perhaps I am not asking the right question.  If this is strange, what is the preferred method for debugging functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't pretty but if you define your function like:

```
function foo(
    (x=1),
    (y=2),
    (z=3)
  ) 

  bar(x,y,z)
end
```

then it works as you describe.