# R: Testing function in interactive session

Tags: r, function, arguments

I am not sure if it is possible, but I would like to be able to grab the default argument values of a function and test them and the code within my functions without having to remove the commas (this is especially useful in the case when there are many arguments).

In effect, I want to be able to have commas when sending arguments into the function but not have those commas if I copy and paste the arguments and run them by themselves.

For example:

```
foo=function(
    x=1,
    y=2,
    z=3
  ) {

  bar(x,y,z)
}
```

Now to test pieces of the function outside of the code block, copy and paste

```
x=1,
y=2,
z=3

bar(x,y,z)
```

But this gives an error because there is a comma after `x=1`

Perhaps I am not asking the right question.  If this is strange, what is the preferred method for debugging functions?

Please note, just posted nearly [identical question in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963870/julia-testing-function-in-interactive-session).

Comment: `?debug` `?debugonce` and `?browser` might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to programmatically get at the arguments of a function and their default values, you can use `formals`:

```
fxn = function(a, b, d = 2) {}
formals(fxn)
# $a
# 
# 
# $b
# 
# 
# $d
# [1] 2
```

I suppose if you wanted to store the default value of every argument to your function into a variable of that name (which is what you're asking about in the OP), then you could do this with a `for` loop:

```
info <- formals(fxn)
for (varname in names(info)) {
  assign(varname, info[[varname]])
}
a
# Error: argument "a" is missing, with no default
b
# Error: argument "b" is missing, with no default
d
# [1] 2
```

So for arguments without default values, you'll need to provide a value after running this code (as you would expect). For arguments with defaults, they'll now be set.